# Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final.But I don't want to declared Final

Tags: java, android, variables, inner-classes

I beginner to programming Android, I declared `Boolean flag`, I want to be set true or false in the inner class and `return flag`, but android studio say you should declare final!!!i don't want to declare final because i set true or false in variable`flag`.
My question is, What should I do right [image: In the picture, you know]

Comment: 'Multiple exclamation marks,' he went on, shaking his head, 'are a sure sign of a diseased mind.' -- in Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering your literal question:**

An inner class doesn't **really** get access to the outside variables (like your `flag`), Java only creates the **illusion** of access.

Technically, you get a field named `flag` (automatically created invisibly by the compiler) with a **copy** of the `flag` variable's content from the moment you instantiate the inner class. It's similar to passing `flag` as an additional argument into the constructor and storing it in a local field of the same name.

But then, to not destroy the **illusion** of access to your `flag` variable, Java forbids you to change `flag`, as technically only the local field could be changed, not the outside variable.

So, a solution for that part (already mentioned by others) is to have a `boolean[] flagHolder = new boolean[1];` and use `flag[0]` for communication.

**But that won't help you in your use case.**

When the `onResponse()` method is called (when receiving your response), your `https()` method has most probably already returned, so it won't be able to see anything that might result from the later response.

**Some formal remark:**

Please, don't show code as screenshots (it's against the stackoverflow rules), but copy it into your question as text. That makes it easier for us to make our own tests and improvements...

Answer (score 2):

Try making the boolean global, as in declare it outside your method.

Answer (score 1):

The request you are doing is async, meaning it will always return false. By the time the result method is called, the value has already been returned. Use callback methods instead for getting the result from an async call

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by declaring an array :

```
final boolean[] flag = {false};
```

And in your onResponse set the value:

```
flag[0] = true;
```

Android Studio automatically propose this solution when you click on the help tooltip.

Comment: Volley is async. Using an array for returning value is meaningless as the value will be false by the time it returns.

Comment: The main question was how to declare it final, not how to make a clean code.

Comment: It isn't about cleaning code, but why declare it final and return the wrong result (and cause more problems) when declaring a callback method is just as easy?

Comment: I answer him the fast solution to declare his variable as global. He will see and learn by himself that he will return the value before onResponse is called. Then he will make something dirty like another boolean to wait if the value is setted and he will finally do your clean solution with a callback method. But a callback method won't solve his question about how to declare it final ;p

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a boolean in a method that is making an asynchronous call to retrieve that return value.

Instead make an interface inside this class, and include an inline implementation of that interface as part of the method signature and call back on success or error.

```
public class yourHTTPClass{
    public void yourMethod(myCallbacks callback){
         doAsyncCall(){
              onSuccess(){
                   callback.onSuccess();
              }
         }
    }
    public interface myCallbacks{
         onSuccess();
         onError();
    }
}

public class OtherClass{
    yourHTTPClassInstance.yourMethod(new myCallbacks(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(){

         }
         @Override
         public void onError(){

         }
    }
}
```

The above is PSEUDO CODE. do NOT copy and paste it. Do not point out that it doesn't compile lol. Just showing you implementation for a call back :). Hope that helps.

Comment: I can return a boolean in a method that is making an asynchronous call, just need to wait until the value is setted by the async call. :)

Comment: this is not C# lol. As soon as your thread leaves to do work, the method continues to the return statement. so you are returning the value of that boolean whatever it is before the call completes. So I'm afraid you are mistaken here :)

Comment: To explain the flow for you. You are essentially doing bool flag = false, Volleyrequest.doYourThing, return flag, volleyRequest.onSuccess or onError. See the problem is you return the flag before the work completes. You must wait for the callback. You can't return in method of async call outs as await doesn't exist in Java

Comment: I am not mistaken, I am talking about java, you can block your method execution until a value is set with a while for exemple. That is a dirty solution but that will work.

Comment: Your code does not have any blocking queues or thread waits, so if you are talking about a different sample then the one supplied sure you can block if you are not on the UI thread

Comment: I am not talking about the answer I shared, I just said you saying was wrong, it is possible to do that :  //Wait until everything is loaded
                    while (!flag[0] ) {
                            MyLog.d(TAG, "Waiting");
                    }

Comment: Well the sample you are asking for help on does an async call out to Volley and then immediately returns a boolean flag. If you don't want help, then don't ask for it lol. You are arguing over trying to prove a point that is not relevant to your question. Your sample is async call out and immediate return of bad value. I provided you a solution and now you argue like you don't need help.

Comment: I am not the one who asked the question.

Comment: oh thank God, you are just trolling. I thought the question person was being rude. Well then I will disregard you thanks